# How deliver an empty page?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I created a simple yesod application and would like to overwrite the default layout.

It can be overwrite in the Foundation.hs file on the Yesod instance as following:

```
instance Yesod App where
    defaultLayout :: Widget -> Handler Html
    defaultLayout widget = ([whamlet|<p>This is my page. I hope you enjoyed it.</p>|])
        --do
        -- master <- getYesod
        -- mmsg <- getMessage

        -- mcurrentRoute <- getCurrentRoute

        -- -- Get the breadcrumbs, as defined in the YesodBreadcrumbs instance.
        -- (title, parents) <- breadcrumbs

        -- -- Define the menu items of the header.
        -- let menuItems =
        --         [ NavbarLeft $ MenuItem
        --             { menuItemLabel = "Home"
        --             , menuItemRoute = HomeR
        --             , menuItemAccessCallback = True
        --             }
        --         ]

        -- let navbarLeftMenuItems = [x | NavbarLeft x <- menuItems]
        -- let navbarRightMenuItems = [x | NavbarRight x <- menuItems]

        -- let navbarLeftFilteredMenuItems = [x | x <- navbarLeftMenuItems, menuItemAccessCallback x]
        -- let navbarRightFilteredMenuItems = [x | x <- navbarRightMenuItems, menuItemAccessCallback x]

        -- -- We break up the default layout into two components:
        -- -- default-layout is the contents of the body tag, and
        -- -- default-layout-wrapper is the entire page. Since the final
        -- -- value passed to hamletToRepHtml cannot be a widget, this allows
        -- -- you to use normal widget features in default-layout.

        -- pc <- widgetToPageContent $ do
        --     addStylesheet $ StaticR css_bootstrap_css
        --     $(widgetFile "default-layout")
        -- withUrlRenderer $(hamletFile "templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet")
```

As you can see, I tried to overwrite with a simple text output but it is not going to be compiled. The compiler complains:

```
    A section must be enclosed in parentheses
      thus: (whamlet |< p > This is my page . I hope you enjoyed it .</ p
             >|)
   |
88 |     defaultLayout widget = [whamlet|<p>This is my page. I hope you enjoyed it.</p>|]
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My goal is, to deliver an empty page.

How to deliver a simple empty page?

Comment: Do you not have the `QuasiQuotes` language extension enabled? It looks like your quasiquote is being parsed as an operator section.

Comment: I believe this is the right way to do this (I'm not sure though). However, I'm not convinced that it's the best idea. What you've done will overwrite the page _for every single handler_, making it impossible to display anything else. I would recommend leaving `defaultLayout` in place, and - depending on your exact needs - editing one or more of `templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet`, `templates/default-layout.hamlet` or `templates/homepage.hamlet`.